# How to search in two columns with one query

Tags: sequelize.js

It is necessary to look in both columns if at one in one not empty or not zero return value. If mURL === "string" and aURL === NULL return value

```
{

    logging: console.log,
    attributes: ['firstName','lastName','email','mURL','aURL'],
    where: {
      mURL: {
        $not: null
      },
      aURL: {
         $not: null
        }
      },        
      include: [
        { all: true, nested: true }
      ]

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to achieve? Select where both fields are not `NULL` or at least one of them is not `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following -

```
{
logging: console.log,
attributes: ['firstName','lastName','email','mURL','aURL'],
where: {
  $or: {
    mURL: {
      $not: null
    },
    aURL: {
      $not: null
    }
  }
  },        
include: [
    { all: true, nested: true }
  ]
```

}

**$and** and **$or** operators can be used.

or you can use -

```
where: Sequelize.literal(`(mURL IS NOT NULL) OR (aURL IS NOT NULL)`)
```